# Отсутствует перевод сообщений о конкурсных вопросах

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, конкурс

Отсутствует перевод сообщения о переводе вопроса в группу конкурсных:

> [image: Конкурс начат]

А также о завершении конкурса:

> [image: Конкурс завершен]

Баг репорт на MSE: [Bounty strings are not used in localization engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296816/339911)

Comment: Ссылку хоть дайте на вопрос )

Comment: @NickVolynkin да любой конкурсный же. Хотя бы [вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/527398/revisions)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, по ссылке теперь ещё один перевод отсутствующий имеется `Конкурс завершен with no winning answer участником`. Стоит ли это в отдельный вопрос выносить или достаточно подредактировать текущий?

Comment: думаю, здесь можно подредактировать, т.к. строки всё равно идут комплектом.

Answer (score 7):

сравнивая [(почти) локализованный вариант](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/527398/revisions) с [«англо»-вариантом сообщения](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37775766/revisions), и пользуясь поиском по *transifex-у*, можно придти к выводу, что данный фрагмент текста вообще не имеет локализации (или она неправильно оформлена в коде или на *transifex-е*).

вот начало фразы:

[tx:996](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262668) `Bounty Started` → `Конкурс начат`

---

а продолжение, по идее, должно быть такое:

1. [tx:6335](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116413) (VARIANT: reputation=few) `worth $amount$ reputation` → `стоимостью $amount$ балла репутации`
2. [tx:6336](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116414) (VARIANT: reputation=many) `worth $amount$ reputation` → `стоимостью $amount$ баллов репутации`
3. [tx:6337](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116415) (VARIANT: reputation=one) `worth $amount$ reputation` → `стоимостью $amount$ балл репутации`

но первый и третий пункты переведены и утверждены (если я правильно интерпретирую предоставленную *transifex-ом* информацию) ещё 3 месяца назад, а второй — год назад.

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

> Объявлен конкурс с наградой в 100 баллов репутации.

[tx:996](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262668) `Bounty Started` → `Объявлен конкурс`

[tx:6335](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116413) (VARIANT: reputation=few) `worth $amount$ reputation` → `с наградой в $amount$ балла репутации`

[tx:6336](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116414) (VARIANT: reputation=many) `worth $amount$ reputation` → `с наградой в $amount$ баллов репутации`

[tx:6337](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/42116415) (VARIANT: reputation=one) `worth $amount$ reputation` → `стоимостью $amount$ балл репутации`

Comment: Может быть, "Объявлен конкурс"? "Начат" как-то больше с "процессом" ассоциируется :)

Comment: @GlebKemarsky хороший вариант.

Comment: По-моему, с `tx:6337` что-то не так в ответе.